# How to extract file paths out of drag and drop event?

Tags: windows-xp

I have this application that lists files in a WindowsForms listbox (NET framework). The application does not support the copy operation if multiple files are selected in the listbox, but at the same time, the application supports 'drag and drop' event for multiple files (allows dragging the files 'out of the application').

How can I extract the paths of the files 'dragged out of the application'? (i.e. I drop the files on some program / script that shows me the paths / saves the paths to a txt file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bat script will work with up to about 15 files, because of the limitation of the cmd.exe:

```
@echo off 
setlocal
:getfile
shift
if "%~1"=="" goto end
echo %1
goto getfile
:end

pause
```

Autohotkey script that bypasses the limitation:

```
; The script displays the file paths. File paths that were
; dropped onto the Text control. AHK Text control. AHK Text control
; that is part of this AHK script.
; The script bypasses the ~2048 cmd.exe input parameters character limitation.
; See here for more info:
; http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473
; http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1666374
; 
Gui, Add, Text, vText1 h80, Drag files here
Gui, Show

return

GuiDropFiles:
    MsgBox, % "A_GuiControl=" A_GuiControl "`n" ; on what AHK control were files dropped
            . "A_EventInfo=" A_EventInfo "`n"   ; number of files
            . "A_GuiEvent =" A_GuiEvent         ; all filenames, divided by `n
    ExitApp
return
```

Comment: There is no windows limitation for 15 files. Would it make sense there there is something else going on with the program? Also, what is the error?

Comment: "Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file.  You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item." The error shows up even if I drag the files onto an empty .bat script.